# How to set the variation of an integral to zero?

Tags: integration, derivatives

So I have an integral:

$$\delta W = \int_{-\Delta}^\Delta \left[ x^2 \left(\frac{d\xi}{dx}\right)^2 - D_s\xi^2 \right] dx$$

Here $\xi$ is a function of $x$ and $D_s$ is a constant. $\Delta$ is just some small $x$. Now I need to set the variation of $\delta W$ to $0$. Do do this I differentiated whatever is inside the bracket and set it to $0$. I get:

$$x^2\xi'' + x\xi' -D_s\xi = 0$$

However, the answer is:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2\frac{d\xi}{dx}\right) + D_s\xi = x^2\xi'' + 2x\xi' + D_s\xi = 0$$

Where the primes are derivatives with respect to $x$. As you can see the difference is a factor of 2 in the middle term and that minus sign.

If anyone could point out where I am going wrong, it would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please mention the reference?

Comment: So I'm basically reading Ideal MHD by Jeffrey Friedberg. If you're familiar with these things then this is the simplification/minimization of delta W for a general screw pinch. However, I have realized where I was going wrong: had to use the Euler Lagrange equation.

Answer (score 0):

I've realised where I'm going wrong, can't just differentiate it like that: Used the Euler Lagrange equation and got the answer!